# Imageeffects: No need for Framebuffer? Just use Textures and Shaders?

Tags: opengl, image-effects

I am doing simple Image Effects, and always i see in examples, that people are binding textures to framebuffers. Why can't i just use textures?

So the process would be.

1) Input Texture
2) Shader: Do Processing on this Shader
3) Render to the same Texture

So no need for framebuffer? This step is done completely linear...no off-screen rendering. So cani say that i don't need a framebuffer in this scenario?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a conflation of naming and the meaning of the names.

When you want to write data from a fragment shader, you use a [*framebuffer* object (FBO)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) with zero or more *render targets* attached as *attachments*. Those render targets can be either [*renderbuffer* objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Objects) or *textures*.

The workflow you have with the traditional pipeline to generate something into a texture is:

- bind output render targets into a framebuffer object and make it active;
- bind all the input textures into your shader program and set all your uniform parameters;
- draw a "full screen" rectangle (two triangles) in such a way that it exactly fills the viewport dimensions;
- in each fragment that this generates, the fragment shader will run and produce an 
  output fragment.

If you have several steps of operations you need to do, it's common to use several textures and bounce between them in a *ping-pong* pattern.

Since OpenGL 4.2 or so, a non-coherent function ['imageStore'](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Image_store) lets you write to arbitrary areas of a bound texture from inside a shader, typically when executing a compute shader.

Comment: I think imageStore can be called from any type of shader (not just compute). It can definitely be called from a fragment shader.

Comment: I see, so as soon i want to gather the result from a shader, i need a framebuffer object (where a texture is attached) to pass the calculated data to it?

Comment: @user1767754 Yes, the FBO is really nothing more than a way to attach a texture (or a few textures) to a fragment shader output, i.e. what you want.